# Does iOS 7 Background Fetch work on cellular 3G network?

Tags: ios, ios7, background-process, 3g, cellular-network

I made a lovely app that fetches updates (using the recommended `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` interval).

**Works fine on WiFi.**

But now I'm testing it on 3G (same code without any modifications), and seemingly it has not yet been updated for half an hour now. Is iOS 7 Background Fetch working on 3G networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

It has a longer duration, but after about 40 minutes it has updated.